# How to comment code in blades like laravel 4?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5

I have migrated my app from laravel 4.2 to laravel 5

I am currently having this problem, when even I have old comments like this:

```
{{--{{link_to_route('language.select', 'English', array('en'))}}--}}
```

Will result into error at laravel 5, I will have this error:

```
FatalErrorException in 18b6386ebc018eb0c0e76f105eba4286 line 263:
syntax error, unexpected '{'
```

which is compiled into:

```
 <?php echo --{{link_to_route('language.select', 'English', array('en')); ?>--}}
```

I already added laravel 4 backward comparability support at register@ServiceProvider as:

```
\Blade::setRawTags('{{', '}}');
\Blade::setContentTags('{{{', '}}}');
\Blade::setEscapedContentTags('{{{', '}}}');
```

but how can I add laravel 4 backward comparability for comments `{{-- --}}` ?

edit:

how to comment this in laravel 5:

```
<li {{ (Request::is('/') ? ' class="active"' : '') }}><a href="{{{ URL::to('') }}}">{{trans('messages.Home')}}</a></li>
```

Comment: if you change {{-- to {{{-- does that work?

Comment: have you tried `{{{-- <li {{ (Request::is('/') ? ' class="active"' : '') }}><a href="{{{ URL::to('') }}}">{{trans('messages.Home')}}</a></li> --}}}` ?

Comment: thanks, it worked, still PHPStorm plugin for laravel does not support this new way to commint..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you change your content tags from `{{` to `{{{` comment tags are now `{{{--` not `{{--`

Answer (score 11):

From [lavarel 5 doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates)

> Note: Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users
>   of your application. Always use the double curly brace syntax to
>   escape any HTML entities in the content.

```
{{-- This comment will not be in the rendered HTML --}}
```

So I think this should works :

```
<li {{-- (Request::is('/') ? ' class="active"' : '') --}}>
     <a href="{{-- URL::to('') --}}">{{--trans('messages.Home')--}}</a>
</li>
```

And to comment the whole HTML add :

```
{{{-- HTML --}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

In general the comment syntax has not changed in Laravel 5, however...

The characters for comments are derived by the *content tags*. Since you set them to `{{{` and `}}}` with `Blade::setContentTags('{{{', '}}}');` you have to use them now for your comments as well:

```
{{{-- {{link_to_route('language.select', 'English', array('en'))}} --}}}
```