# How to add two types of content tags to Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm preparing a Laravel 4 blades to be upgraded in the future to Laravel 5. I wanted to make it possible for the developer to use `{{ }}` and `{!! !!}` for the same purpose, that is as content tags.

Laravel 5 has the `Blade::setRawTags()` but in Laravel 4 there is no equivalent.

I'm researching this especially for the purpose of making `{{--` comments work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217795/how-to-comment-code-in-blades-like-laravel-4

Comment: I knew how to make comments work, but I needed to make `{{--` work.